# egeloen/ivory-google-map load only one map

Tags: symfony

I am using egeloen/ivory-google-map library to show map for each registered user. But in all user list only one map is showing.

This is my method:

```
public function findCompaniesAction() {
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$companies = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('b')
    ->from('RFQIronilBundle:User',  'b')
    ->where('b.acc_type = 1')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

foreach ($companies as $key => $company) {
    $map = $this->get('ivory_google_map.map');
    $map->setMapOption('mapTypeId', MapTypeId::ROADMAP);
    $map->setMapOption('mapTypeId', 'roadmap');
    $company->map = $map;
}

return $this->render('RFQIronilBundle:Default:find-companies.html.twig', array(
    'companies'     => $companies
));
}
```

and in my view I use:

```
{% for companies in companies %}
    {{ google_map_container(companies.map) }}
    {{ google_map_js(companies.map) }}
{% endfor %}
```

All is fine, but map is showing for only first user. What I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving each map a unique container id.  I use something like this:

```
$map->setHtmlContainerId('map_canvas_'.md5($address));
```

where $address is a simple address string.